# NSTextView: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have seen other questions similar to this, but was not able to use any of the solutions.

.h

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextView *commandOutput;
```

.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    Command *aCommand = [[Command alloc] init];
    [self setCommand:aCommand];

    if (self.commandOutput) NSLog(@"textView is not nil");
    [self.commandOutput setString:@""];
}
```

The error message I get is: `-[NSScrollView setString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100608630`

I also see that: `textView is not nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suspect from the error message is that you bound your `commandOutput` outlet to the inner `NSScrollView` within a `NSTextView`. If you use this log trace, you can have more info about the real type of `self.commandOutput`:

```
if (self.commandOutput) NSLog(@"textView is not nil: %@", [self.commandOutput description]);
```

So, my suggestion is check your bindings in Interface Builder and make sure you did not inadvertently dragged the outlet onto the wrong view.